# How add quotation marks to each element of the DOMDocument XML to save in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, domdocument, xmldom

Sorry for english, not my native language.

So, I am trying to save each element between XML tags in the my MySQL database. Is all looking good, but I need to add " " to each element. Look:

XML (If this would help)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<layout>
    <encabezado>
        <fecha_reporte> 2017-01-31</fecha_reporte>
        <fecha_esperada>2017-02-28 </fecha_esperada>
    </encabezado>

    <detalle>   
        <matricula>20152999 </matricula>
        <nombre>Ivan </nombre>
        <creditos_costo>1100 </creditos_costo>
        <creditos_cursar>20 </creditos_cursar>
        <creditos_monto> 22000</creditos_monto>
    </detalle>

    <piedepagina>
        <total_estudiantes> 1</total_estudiantes>
        <total_creditos>20 </total_creditos>
        <monto_totalcred>22000 </monto_totalcred>       
    </piedepagina>
</layout>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

require ('conexion.php');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Layout.xml');
$estudiante= $doc->saveXML();

$escapando = mysql_real_escape_string($estudiante);
$query = "INSERT INTO nomina (fecha_reporte, fecha_esperada, matricula, 
nombre, creditos_costo, creditos_cursar, creditos_monto, 
total_estudiante, total_creditos, monto_totalcred) VALUES ('$escapando')";

echo $query;

?>
```

The `echo $query;` is giving to me this line: `INSERT INTO nomina (fecha_reporte, fecha_esperada, matricula, nombre, creditos_costo, creditos_cursar, creditos_monto, total_estudiante, total_creditos, monto_totalcred) VALUES ('\n\n  \n  2017-01-31\n 2017-02-28 \n  \n  \n  \n  20152999 \n Ivan \n 1100 \n 20 \n   22000\n \n  \n  \n  1\n 20 \n   22000 \n    \n\n')` if I remove `mysql_real_escape_string` the echo will print without `\n` so I think I should remove it.

How can I do to add "" to each element? for example, like this:
`INSERT INTO nomina (fecha_reporte, fecha_esperada, matricula, nombre, creditos_costo, creditos_cursar, creditos_monto, total_estudiante, total_creditos, monto_totalcred) VALUES ('2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '20152999' 'Ivan', '1100', '20', '22000', '1',   '20', '22000')`

Comment: Consider parameterized queries to avoid any quotes or even MySQL's own [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html). And **definitely** avoid the deprecated mysql* and discontinued in PHP 7.

Comment: Why don't you properly parse the document you are importing?

Comment: @Parfait Yes, i will update to sqli, ty.

Comment: @NicoHasee I will investigate about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work if you did something like this

```
INSERT INTO nomina (fecha_reporte, fecha_esperada, matricula, nombre, creditos_costo, creditos_cursar, creditos_monto, total_estudiante, total_creditos, monto_totalcred) VALUES ('"2017-01-31"', '"2017-02-28"', '"20152999"' '"Ivan"', '"1100"', '"20"', '"22000"', '"1"',   '"20"', '"22000"')
```

However, if you store the query in double quotes, like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bla VALUES (blabla)";
```

Then the query should be:

```
INSERT INTO nomina (fecha_reporte, fecha_esperada, matricula, nombre, creditos_costo, creditos_cursar, creditos_monto, total_estudiante, total_creditos, monto_totalcred) VALUES ('\"2017-01-31\"', '\"2017-02-28\"', '\"20152999\"' '\"Ivan\"', '\"1100\"', '\"20\"', '\"22000\"', '\"1\"',   '\"20\"', '\"22000\"')
```

Escaping the double quotes should work.